# Cannot pull data from pantip.com

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

I have been trying to pull data from pantip.com including title, post stoy and all comments using beautifulsoup. 
However, I could pull only title and post stoy. I could not get comments.
Here is code for title and post stoy

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# specify the url
url = 'https://pantip.com/topic/38372443'

# Split Topic number
topic_number = re.split('https://pantip.com/topic/', url)
topic_number = topic_number[1]


page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Capture title
elementTag_title = soup.find(id = 'topic-'+ topic_number)
title = str(elementTag_title.find_all(class_ = 'display-post-title')[0].string)

# Capture post story
resultSet_post = elementTag_title.find_all(class_ = 'display-post-story')[0]
post = resultSet_post.contents[1].text.strip()
```

I tried to find by id

```
elementTag_comment = soup.find(id = "comments-jsrender")
```

according to
[image]

I got the result below.

elementTag_comment  =

```
<div id="comments-jsrender">
<div class="loadmore-bar loadmore-bar-paging"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> 
<span class="icon-expand-left"><small>▼</small></span> <span class="focus- 
txt"><span class="loading-txt">กำลังโหลดข้อมูล...</span></span> <span 
class="icon-expand-right"><small>▼</small></span> </a> </div>
</div>
```

The question is how can I get all comments. Please, suggest me how to fix it.

Comment: At a glance, it seems theres lazy loading for the posts. ( Comments are loaded asynchronously after page). If you look at the network tab, you can see a 'render_comments' resource  network call is made...Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851306/6283258

Comment: `soup.find()` will only return the first element is finds. If you want all tags with id = "comments-jsrender", you need to use `soup.find_all()`. Then depending what you want to do, may need to iterate through each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your having trouble locating the rest of these posts is because the site is populated with dynamic javascript. To get around this you can implement a solution with selenium, see here how to get the correct driver and add to your system variables https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases . Selenium will load the page and you will have full access to all the attributes you see in your screenshot, with just beautiful soup that data is not being parsed.

Once you do that you can use the following to return each of the posts data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://pantip.com/topic/38372443'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
content=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all("div", id=lambda value: value and value.startswith("comment-")):
    if len(str(div.text).strip()) > 1:
        print(str(div.text).strip())

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder whether I can do that without Web Browser popping up. I think it may help increase speed.